# React Router - Open Link on new Tab and Redirect to Home Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

> Using React Router 4.2

My attempt is to **open** a new tab upon clicking on a navigation link and at the same time be **redirected** to the site homepage.

ie: Navigation bar: clicking on Policies

[image]

Even though the code bellow behaves as the requirements above: Is this the advisable way to go about it?
Aiming to learn best practices here on Routes.js.

```js
 //Routes.js
 import HandbookDoc from './policies.pdf'
 ...

 <Route 
   path="/registration/policies" 
   component={() => window.open(`${HandbookDoc}`,'_blank').then(window.location= '/')} 
 />
```

....

```
 //Navigation.js (using react-router-bootstrap)
  <NavDropdown eventKey={3} id="formId" title="Registration">
     <LinkContainer to="/registration/financial-aid">
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Financial Aid</MenuItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      <LinkContainer to="/registration/policies">
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Policies</MenuItem>
      </LinkContainer>
  </NavDropdown>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the path `/registration/policies` to exist here? I would simply add an onClick listener on `policies`, and just do the stuffs you need there.

Comment: The path set on `routes.js` is matching the same passed on `navigation.js`. How would you go about just setting an onClick on that case?

Comment: By adding an onClick handler on `MenuItem` that contains `Policies`. In there, you would be able to do `window.open()`, and `browserHistory.push('/')`

Comment: Indeed. Mind posting an answer? I haven't played much with `browserHistory.push()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to create a new route for the thing you are trying to achieve. You could add an `onClick` handler to the `MenuItem` like this:

```
  <NavDropdown eventKey={3} id="formId" title="Registration">
     <LinkContainer to="/registration/financial-aid">
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Financial Aid</MenuItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      <LinkContainer 
        to="/">
        <MenuItem onClick={this.handlePoliciesClick} eventKey={3.2}>Policies</MenuItem>
      </LinkContainer>
  </NavDropdown>
```

And then in same component add the handler:

```
handlePoliciesClick = () => {
  window.open(HandbookDoc, '_blank');
}
```

Remember to import your `HandbookDoc`.

Comment: Thank you so much, visualizing your explanation/suggestion through the code made sense in my head now. The only issue is that `browserHistory` is not redirecting home...

Comment: Have you removed the `to` attribute in your `LinkContainer`?

Comment: I did. In fact, I removed LinkContainer all together, cause `to` is required on their api, it was throwing an error otherwise.

Comment: Weird. Is browserHistory redirecting you somewhere else? Or it just doesn't work at all?

Comment: it stays on the same page. Scenario 2. If I leave `to="/"` it redirects me home. Which means BrowserHistory alone is not getting triggered. But the open on new tab click handler works.